# Comparing two rows in the same table SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

We are having trouble solving a part of an exercise in a SQL-course, here is a part of the dataset: [image]

The query we are looking for should: Find the diseases that can be treated with hydrocortisone but not with etanercept.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS you are using.  MsSqlServer, PostGres, MySql, etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by DiseaseName and set the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
select DiseaseName
from tablename
where DrugName in ('hydrocortisone', 'etanercept') 
group by DiseaseName
having count(case when DrugName = 'etanercept' then 1 end) = 0
```

In Mysql the difference would be the `having` clause:

```
having sum(DrugName = 'etanercept') = 0
```

And in Potgresql:

```
having sum((DrugName = 'etanercept')::int) = 0
```

Another way with NOT EXISTS:

```
select DISTINCT t.DiseaseName
from tablename t
where t.DrugName = 'hydrocortisone'
and not exists (select 1 from tablename where DiseaseName = t.DiseaseName and DrugName = 'etanercept')
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide this in MySql, as we are comparing various RDBMS

Comment: @lebech . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  If you have a question about a different database, then it should be asked as a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query:

```
SELECT "diseasename" FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY  "diseasename"
HAVING MIN("DRUGNAME") = MAX("DRUGNAME") AND MAX("DRUGNAME") = 'hydrocortisone';
```